# How does .prototype works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started a tutorial in game development using JavaScript and HTML5. javascript.prototype has come into play many times. I can not really understand how it works. Here is a link I found with a good explanation, but I am still a little bit confused

[How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work).

Can anyone explain this please? 
Here is an example of my code:

```
 function Enemy(){
        this.srcX = 140;  //gets the location of enemy in x and Y here
        this.srcY = 600;
        this.width = 45;//gets the enemies width and height here
        this.height = 54; 
        this.drawX = randomRange(0, canvasWidth  - this.width);
        this.drawY = randomRange(0, canvasHeight - this.height); 
        this.centerX = this.drawX + (this.width / 2);
        this.centerY = this.drawY +(this.height / 2);

        //this.targetX = this.centerX;
        //this.targetY = this.centerY;
        //this.randomMoveTime = randomRange(4000,10000);
        this.speed = 1;
        //var that = this;
        //this.moveInterval = setInterval(function() {that.setTargetLocation();},that.randomMOveTime);
        this.isDead = false;
    }

    Enemy.prototype.update = function() {
        //this.checkDirection();
         this.centerX = this.drawX + (this.width / 2);
        this.centerY = this.drawY + (this.height / 2);
    }
```

Comment: Magic. In seriousness though, it literally just means "All Enemy objects will have an `update` function".

Comment: *"but I am still a little bit confused"* About what exactly? What exactly from the answers in the other question did you not understand? Does it help if I tell you that `new Enemy()` is (roughly) equivalent to `var newObj = Object.create(Enemy.prototype); Enemy.apply(newObj, arguments); return newObj;` ?

Comment: @FelixKling I totally understand that, I just don't understand that udpate part that comes after prototype

Comment: `Enemy.prototype` is an object. `Enemy.prototype.update = function() {...};` assigns a function to the `update` property of that object. Since the property doesn't exist yet, it is created. Simpler example: `var foo = {}; foo.bar = function() { console.log('hi'); }; foo.bar();`. This has nothing to do with prototypes. This is how objects in JavaScript work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @FelixKling in this case we are creating the update property for the enemy object. It has nothing to do with a different function I have which is called update

Comment: @Alexander: Is that a question? I have no idea what you are trying to tell me with that comment.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry English is my second language. In this case update is a property of Enemy.property object.

Comment: Yes, I never claimed it isn't.

Comment: @FelixKling okay, my question is. I also have a function "method" that is called update which I did not mention here. Is that function related to the update property?

Comment: You mean you have `Enemy.prototype.update = ...;` and `function update() { ... }` somewhere? No, they are not related. Just like `foo.bar` and `bar` are not related in this example: `var foo = {}; foo.bar = 42; var bar = 21;`.

Comment: @FelixKling yes that's what I meant. Thank you

Comment: Maybe the following can help you understand what the prototype and constructor functions are used for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest confusion over prototype inheritance is that that objects inherit from their contructor's *prototype* via their internal `[[Prototype]]` property. Both are referred to as "the prototype". All functions have a default *prototype* property that is an empty object.

In your case:

```
function Enemy(){
        this.srcX = 140;  //gets the location of enemy in x and Y here
        this.srcY = 600;
        ...
}
```

is a function that, when called with *new*, acts as a constructor that assigns properties to a new instance of itself. That instance has an internal `[[Prototype]]` property that points to *Enemy.prototype*.

Then:

```
Enemy.prototype.update = function() {
    //this.checkDirection();
     this.centerX = this.drawX + (this.width / 2);
    this.centerY = this.drawY + (this.height / 2);
}
```

This assigns a new property to *Enemy.prototype* that is a function. So that puts an *update* property on the inheritance chain of all instances of *Enemy*, so they all inherit an *update* method.

So:

```
var enemy0 = new Enemy();
var enemy1 = new Enemy();

typeof enemy0.update // function
typeof enemy1.update // function

enemy0.update === enemy1.update  // true
```

The test can only be true if both expressions reference the same object (i.e. the function assigned to *Enemy.prototype.update*).

You can continue to add properties and methods to *Enemy.prototype* and they will be inherited by all instances, even those already constructed. But if you change it to a different object:

```
Enemy.prototype = {update:function(){/*new update function*/}};
```

then old instances will still have the old `[[Prototype]]` and new instances will have the new one.

There are a million articles on the web about javascript's prototype inheritance, read a few and play with it, ask more questions if you have them. :-)